# how to get react native dependencies with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, native

[Integration With Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html), 
I follow the tutorial, embedded in the native app, but

```
# The target name is most likely the name of your project.
target 'NumberTileGame' do

  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
  # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]

end
```

how can I get the dependency name ? I ceate a react-native project demo and embed in the native iOS app, but it prompt lack of module.
[errorScreenImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XuEM.png). SomeBody help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependencies problem,but not about cocoapods.The error says that you use a react-native-tab-navigator in main.js, but it can't find that.

please follow the github README [react-native-tab-navigator](https://github.com/exponent/react-native-tab-navigator)

Or if you want a quick solution:

1. cd node_modules and try to find react-native-tab-navigator folder, if not exist，install it again with:

```js
npm install react-native-tab-navigator --save
```

2.Look at main.js ,did you import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';?

And if you want a further help, please show others your code.